# grep command line, linux

Tags: linux, grep

i'm trying to isolate all the server names (i.e sv012-cali) from within an html file "Servernick":"sv012-cali" in the line code below I think its the quotation mark that's throwing it off

`cat smtest.html | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^Servernick":"" | cut -d '"' -f 2`

snippet of the html data file **"Relation":0},{"ID":415804","Servernick":"sv012-cali","Level":"3"**

Comment: It would help if you can show a snippet of the file you're parsing.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on either superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated after OP provided sample data -**

```
# cat test.data                                                  
"Relation":0},{"ID":415804","Servernick":"sv012-cali","Level":"3"
"Relation":0},{"ID":415804","Servernick":"sv012-balh","Level":"3"
# cat test.data | tr "," "\n" | grep Servernick | cut -d '"' -f 4
sv012-cali
sv012-balh
```

**Original reply -**

Is this what you need?

```
# echo \"Servernick\":\"sv012-cali\"  > test.data  
# cat test.data                                  
"Servernick":"sv012-cali"
# cat test.data  | tr '"' '\n'                                          

Servernick
:
sv012-cali

# cat test.data  | tr '"' '\n' | egrep -v "Servernick|:|^$"
sv012-cali
```

Comment: this sort of works... there is other html coding and similar strings with ":" in it, so it has to be specific when looking for "Servernick":"sv012-cali" ... here is a bigger snippet of the data file "Relation":0},{"ID":415804","Servernick":"sv012-cali","Level":"3"

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quotes. In bash use `\` to escape characters:

```
grep "^Servernick\":\""
```

or alternatively put your double quotes within single quotes:

```
grep '^servernick":"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quote when dealing with strings containing double quotes :

```
grep '^Servernick":"'
```